# Как десериализовать json-строку, содержающую сериализованный json-объект, представляющий полиморфный тип?

Tags: java, json, kotlin, классы, jackson

Есть json-объект, одно из полей которого представляет из себя json-строку, содержащую сериализованный json-объект,
который необходимо десериализовать в полиморфный тип. Как это сделать с помощью jackson-аннотаций? Используемая версия jackson `2.14.0`.
Если на уровне кода, то надо как-то поменять `data class`'ы, чтобы тест проходил:

```kotlin
data class Zoo(
    val animal: Animal
)

@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
    property = "type"
)
@JsonSubTypes(
    JsonSubTypes.Type(Cat::class, name = "cat"),
    JsonSubTypes.Type(Dog::class, name = "dog"),
)
interface Animal

data class Cat(
    val meow: String,
) : Animal

data class Dog(
    val woof: String,
) : Animal

class TestDeser {
    private val objectMapper: ObjectMapper = ObjectMapper().findAndRegisterModules()

    @Test
    fun testDeserialize() {
        val catJson = "{\"animal\":\"{\\\"type\\\":\\\"cat\\\",\\\"meow\\\":\\\"catValue\\\"}\"}"
        val dogJson = "{\"animal\":\"{\\\"type\\\":\\\"dog\\\",\\\"woof\\\":\\\"dogValue\\\"}\"}"

        val zooWithCat = this.objectMapper.readValue<Zoo>(catJson)
        val cat = zooWithCat.animal
        Assertions.assertTrue(cat is Cat)
        cat as Cat
        Assertions.assertEquals("catValue", cat.meow)

        val zooWithDog = this.objectMapper.readValue<Zoo>(dogJson)
        val dog = zooWithDog.animal
        Assertions.assertTrue(dog is Dog)
        dog as Dog
        Assertions.assertEquals("dogValue", dog.woof)
    }
}
```

---

Что я пробовал:

1. Пробовал написать свой `JsonDeserializer`:

   ```kotlin
   class MyDeserializer : StdDeserializer<Animal>(Animal::class.java) {
       override fun deserialize(p: JsonParser, ctxt: DeserializationContext): Animal {
           val str = p.valueAsString
           return (p.codec as ObjectMapper).readValue(str)
       }
   }

   data class Zoo(
       @JsonDeserialize(using = MyDeserializer::class)
       val animal: Animal,
   )
   ```

   Этот подход я использовал для обычных типов, не полиморфных, и он работал. Для полиморфного типа в
   метод `deserialize` даже не заходит.
2. Хотел попробовать использовать `Converter`

   ```kotlin
   class MyConverter : StdConverter<String, Animal>() {
      override fun convert(value: String): Animal {
         TODO("Нет доступа к ObjectMapper :(")
      }
   }

   data class Zoo(
      @JsonDeserialize(converter = MyConverter::class)
      val animal: Animal,
   )
   ```

   Но в случае использования конвертера нет доступа к `ObjectMapper`, чтобы строку преобразовать в POJO

Comment: @Nowhere Man Вопрос одинаков и имеет смысл что для java, что для kotlin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Забыл про условие, что можем менять только класс `Zoo`. `Animal` и его потомков менять не можем.

---

Получилось накидать такое кривое, но рабочее решение:

```kotlin
class StringEncodedJsonDeserializer : JsonDeserializer<Any>() {
    override fun deserialize(
        p: JsonParser,
        ctxt: DeserializationContext,
    ): Any {
        val str = p.valueAsString
        return (p.codec as ObjectMapper).readValue(str)
    }

    override fun deserializeWithType(
        p: JsonParser,
        ctxt: DeserializationContext,
        typeDeserializer: TypeDeserializer,
    ): Any {
        val raw = this.deserialize(p, ctxt)
        return (p.codec as ObjectMapper)
            .convertValue(
                raw,
                (typeDeserializer as TypeDeserializerBase).baseType()
            )
    }
}

data class Zoo(
    @JsonDeserialize(using = StringEncodedJsonDeserializer::class)
    val animal: Animal,
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Давно не юзал `Jackson`, возможно и через `JsonSubTypes` как-то можно, но вот так точно работает.

```
class MyDeserializer : StdDeserializer<Animal>(Animal::class.java) {
    override fun deserialize(p: JsonParser, ctxt: DeserializationContext): Animal? {
        val animal = p.readValueAsTree<JsonNode>().asText()
        return when {
            animal.contains("cat") -> {
                (p.codec as ObjectMapper).readValue(animal, Cat::class.java)
            }
            animal.contains("dog") -> {
                (p.codec as ObjectMapper).readValue(animal, Dog::class.java)
            }
            else -> { // не обязательно
                null
            }
        }
    }
}

data class Zoo(
    @JsonDeserialize(using = MyDeserializer::class)
    @JsonProperty("animal")
    val animal: Animal
)

interface Animal

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
data class Cat(
    @JsonProperty("meow")
    val meow: String,
) : Animal

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
data class Dog(
    @JsonProperty("woof")
    val woof: String,
) : Animal
```

Answer (score 0):

В Gson это делается через одно место. При сериализации вставляем дополнительное поле куда вписываем тип, при десериализации разворачиваем в реальный класс, примерно так:

```
public class FieldMarshaller implements JsonDeserializer<Field>, JsonSerializer<Field> {
    public final String FIELD_META_KEY="clz";

    @Override
    public Field deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        JsonObject jsonObj = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
        String className = jsonObj.get(FIELD_META_KEY).getAsString();
        try {
            Class<?> clz = Class.forName(className);
            return context.deserialize(jsonElement, clz);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new JsonParseException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Field field, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        JsonElement jsonElement = context.serialize(field, typeOfSrc);
        jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().addProperty(FIELD_META_KEY, field.getClass().getCanonicalName());
        return jsonElement;
    }
}
```

В данном примере производится сериализация/десериализация абстрактного класса `Field`. Во время сериализации вставляем дополнительное поле clz, куда записываем имя класса, а при десериализации вызываем его десериализатор передавая ему реальное имя класса.

Вообще лучше перейти на kotlinx-serialization - он автоматически поддерживает сериализацию/десериализацию абстрактных sealed классов, [примеры здесь](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/polymorphism.md)